# arduino-sim300 gsm communication

Tags: arduino, serial, gsm

I am establishing a serial connection between the arduino uno and the sim300 gsm module.One way of doing is removing the max232 circuit and soldering tx rx wires from there onto the arduino board. A second way is to use a RS232/TTL convertor(http://goo.gl/M6Lxf).

I tried the second method.I connected the convertor to the arduino using a db9 to db9 connector.But no serial connection seems to have been established when I tried a basic program of sending a sms whose code goes like this:

```
char phone_no[]="<phone number>"; //phone number

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600); //Open Serial connection at baud 9600

delay(2000);

Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); //set GSM to text mode

delay(200);

}

void loop() {

delay(1500);

Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");

Serial.print(phone_no);

Serial.println("\"");

while(Serial.read()!='>');

{

  Serial.print("Test Message");  //SMS body 

delay(500); 

Serial.write(0x1A);  // sends ctrl+z end of message 

Serial.write(0x0D);  // Carriage Return in Hex 

Serial.write(0x0A);  // Line feed in Hex 
}

}
```

The connections I made are : RX of ttl convertor to RX of arduino.

TX of ttl convertor to TX of arduino.

gnd to gnd.

5V of convertor to 5V of arduino.

The code was successfully uploaded to the board but the setup is not working.I tried crossing the RX,TX connections by connecting RX to TX and TX to RX.But it was of no use.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Rx to Tx and Tx to Rx - this is the way to do it and keep it this way until you have possibly found the error in your code unless you can't upload your code anymore. In which case revert to how you had it.

Answer (score -2):

make phone number as string then use this command "AT+CMGS\="091********\"\r" THE back slash r means carriage return or simply enter no need to put ln

Comment: Your sentence seems to be incomplete? If you submitted it too early you can go back and edit at any time.

Comment: Please edit your answer to be a bit more coherent. 1-line fly-by answers lower the overall quality of content on the site.